# How to add external JavaScript or CSS files to our Tridion page?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have an external *JavaScript* and a *CSS* file . I am not getting the idea how to add this file to my page. I am using *DWT TBBs* for both *CTs and PTs*.

I am writing internal CSS in my page TBB for getting the output for the time being. but I am not getting how to implement JavaScript. Can somebody help me?

Should I make these file as component and render them on my page? Is this the correct way? If yes, please tell me the steps to be followed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a topic for wide discussion, I'll try to outline the various possibilities:

1. Create CSS & JS as Binary Components, link to these from DWT template
2. Create CSS & JS as Binary Components, publish to Server as DCP, link with url to binary
3. Create CSS & JS as Text components, place in page, publish to server, link url to page
4. Copy CSS & JS to delivery server (not Tridion), link with url to css & js

Option #1 is the easiest, with quite a few drawbacks.

- Create Multimedia Components in Tridion with the CSS and JS files you need.
- Note down the URIs then use something like this in your DWT:

```xml
<link href="tcm:27-2762" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="tcm:27-2763" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If your template uses the Default Finish Actions Building Block, then Tridion will resolve the references to those binaries and publish it with your page.
This has the side-effect that these binaries would be published with ALL pages that use the same template.

Option #2 requires you to write a Dynamic Component Template, possibly with some code to determine where files get published to. This is more in line with what I normally implement, but at this point in time I would not recommend that you do this. As you grow Tridion knowledge, you'll feel comfortable enough to do this by yourself. Using this option you can then publish the CSS/JS files to a given location, then use references in your DWT that instead of using the TCM URIs (as above) would use the URL that the files get published to.

Option #3 requires you to create a "code component & template", meaning a simple schema with just one large text field (not rich text) where copy/paste the content of your CSS or JS. Then write a simple component template that will just output the content as is. Something like `@@Fields.Code@@`.
Lastly you create 2 page templates (one with extension .js, the other with extension .css) with only one DW Template:

```xml
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Components" -->
@@RenderComponentPresentation()@@
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

Last, and definitely not least (there's many ways to skin this cat) you could just place these CSS/JS files directly on your webserver, and add a link in your DWT to the URLs where these files are available.

Hope this gives you some options. Remember that including CSS/JS should be done at Page Template Level (ideally in the `<head>` portion of your page), and not in your Component Template.

Comment: thank you very much sir , i got all the information that i needed, even more, thank u once again

Comment: One common approach to preventing the excessive publishing associated with some of these techniques is to use a server-side include for the CSS and JS links in the head element.

Answer (score 5):

There is a great series of how to articles from Building Blocks that explains this

Check out these links:

1. http://blog.building-blocks.com/publishing-code-files-from-sdl-tridion
2. http://blog.building-blocks.com/css-in-sdl-tridion-part-2-handling-image-references
3. http://blog.building-blocks.com/tridion-tbb-automatically-minify-css-javascript-on-publish

If you want to keep things really simple (but I don't recommend this as it will republish your CSS or JS every time you publish a page). You can store the CSS as a Multimedia Component (and write down its URI) and reference it like this in your DWT Page Layout:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="tcm:1-2-16" />

    or

<script type="text/javascript" src="tcm:1-2-16"></script>
```

Then use the Default Finish Actions to make sure the binary is published and the links are resolved.

Comment: there they were using c# TBBs to do so, can't we have any other option in DWT TBB ?

Comment: I would suggest following one of the linked approaches, but I have updated my answer with an additional approach. Please also consider committing to the SDL Tridion proposal at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=eo63snjNlUWNn9xqeeO2NA2 we really need the entire Tridion development community to help us create a great Q&A platform