# how to access the .css files in Page TBB which are uploaded as Binaries in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am uploading the .css files as binaries(In a separate multimedia schema) in SDL Tridion 2011 CME.

I have two options.

```
1.Writing the TBB and CT for the CS and access it
2.Publishing the .css as binary and access it
  I doubt that whether we can access the published binaries through the TBB.
```

My page TBB uses the Dreamweaver Templating.

I am not sure about the best approach.

Can some one tell the best approach to do this.

Comment: I gave a pretty detailed answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10556174/866454

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add external JavaScript or CSS files to our Tridion page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555177/how-to-add-external-javascript-or-css-files-to-our-tridion-page)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you asking how to publish CSS files from Tridion?

If so there are several approaches, one is documented here:

http://blog.building-blocks.com/publishing-code-files-from-sdl-tridion

Answer (score 1):

Here is another good article to Easily Publish Web Site Designs :

http://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/publish-design-the-basics.aspx