# Adding the .css and JavaScript files directly under server and accessing them in TBBs

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add external JavaScript or CSS files to our Tridion page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555177/how-to-add-external-javascript-or-css-files-to-our-tridion-page)

I want to add the .css and .js files to the Tridion server.

I want to refer them in the TBBs.

```
<link href="path/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="path/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have some questions:

1. Do I need to place them directly in Tridion server machine?
2. Do I need to add them in IIS as virtual directories to refer them?

In either of the ways I am not sure how to give the "href".

I am using Dreamweaver TBBs and SDL Tridion 2011 SP1.

I know that there are other ways to handle the .css and scripts.

But my requirement needs them to add directly in server.

Please share your suggestions.

Comment: #2 depends on if your links need a virtual path. See [publication settings](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_95E217D424DB42B993B09495672DEABC) on how to set the `Images path` (which exists on the presentation server as a physical folder) and `Images url` (which can add a virtual path for you). This only applies if the binaries are Tridion-managed multimedia components, though.

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on where the files are on the local disk (which unfortunately you fail to mention in your question).

If you have the files on disk like this:

```
c:\
   inetpub
       wwwroot
           mywebsite
               index.html
               style.css
               script.js
```

And you have created a web site with its root at `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mywebste`, then you can refer to `style.css` and `script.js` from within `index.html` as

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If however you created a web site with its root at `c:\inetpub\wwwroot`, you'd refer to the same files as:

```
<link href="mywebsite/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="mywebsite/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Either way, you will have to ensure that the files are placed onto the web server. You can either do that through Tridion or by placing them there manually.

If you want to publish the CSS and JavaScript files from Tridion, I suggest reading this question: [How to add external JavaScript or CSS files to our Tridion page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555177/how-to-add-external-javascript-or-css-files-to-our-tridion-page)